# JDBC JTable image

Tags: java, user-interface, jdbc, jtable

I have an item database (jdbc) the functionality is: insert, delete, and update using GUI JTable, all work good but I need to display the image in the JTable but I couldn't :(

If you could help me in that, here's the code for the main functionality:

fill Table method:

```
   try{          
connection= DriverManager.getConnection(url, usr, pas);
statement = connection.createStatement();
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from item");
itemTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(resultSet));

        } catch(SQLException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);}
```

add method:

```
try{
PreparedStatement  insert =connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO items"
        +"(name, price, image, ID)"
        +"VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
        insert.setString(1, nameTextField.getText());
        insert.setDouble(2, Double.parseDouble(priceTextField.getText()));
        insert.setByte(3, image);
        insert.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(IDTextField.getText()));
        int row = insert.executeUpdate(); 
        fillTable();

        }catch (SQLException ex){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);}
```

update method:

```
try{
PreparedStatement  update =connection.prepareStatement("update item set "
                    + "name=? , price=?, image=? where id=?""
                    +"VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
        update.setString(1, nameTextField.getText());
        update.setDouble(2, Double.parseDouble(priceTextField.getText()));
        update.setByte(3, image);
        update.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(IDTextField.getText()));
        int row = update.executeUpdate(); 
        fillTable();

        }catch (SQLException ex){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);}
```

delete method:

```
try{
Statement delete = connection.createStatement();
delete.executeUpdate("delete from item where id="+IDTextField.getText());

                    priceTextField.setText("");
                    nameTextField.setText("");                   
                    idTextField.setText("");
                    fillTable();
}catch (SQLException ex){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);}
```

A button event to choose image from JFileChooser:

```
String imagePath = null;
JFileChooser file;

private void ChooseImageButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){  
    int result =  file.showSaveDialog(null);
    if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        File selectedFile = file.getSelectedFile();
        String path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
        imagePath = path;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The important methods are fillTable() and add().

fillTable method could be like this:

```
//you need a TableModel, let´s call it model and let´s call your JTable myJTable
   TableModel model = (javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel) myJTable.getModel();
    myJTable.setModel(model);

    //try to add results
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usr, pas);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from item");
        while (resultSet.next()) {  
        //after your query, get the Image
        Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob(3);//column 3
            byte[] data = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
            BufferedImage img = null;
            img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));

        Icon imgToTable = imageToIcon(img);//use the method below
        //add row to your table (throught the model)
        model.addRow(new Object[]{resultSet.getObject(1).toString(), resultSet.getObject(2).toString(), imgToTable,resultSet.getObject(4).toString()});
        //itemTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(resultSet));
     }
     resultSet.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
```

Add method could be like this:

```
try{
PreparedStatement  insert =connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO items"
    +"(name, price, image, ID)"
    +"VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
    insert.setString(1, nameTextField.getText());
    insert.setDouble(2, Double.parseDouble(priceTextField.getText()));
   //i recommend to use something like this to configure you image

   file = new File(imagePath);

   fis = new FileInputStream(file);
   if (null == fis) {              
     fis = new FileInputStream(imagePath);                
   }
    //configure image
   insert.setBinaryStream(3, fis);
   // insert.setByte(3, image);
    insert.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(IDTextField.getText()));
    int row = insert.executeUpdate(); 
    fillTable();

    }catch (SQLException ex){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);}
```

And use this to convert from Image to Icon (to put it in a Table Cell):

```
//from Image a Icon
public Icon imageToIcon(Image image) {
    ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon(image);
    Icon iconReturn = (Icon) imgIcon;
    return iconReturn;
}
```

If in your database you are not using blob let me know.

Comment: A `BufferedImage` already is an `Image`, so there is no need for that `bufferedImageToImage` method, same goes for the explicit cast from `ImageIcon` to `Icon`: an `ImageIcon` **is** an `Icon`, the cast is not needed. Note that your answer is largely guessing at what the problem of the OP might be, given their lack of information: don't answer unclear questions.

Comment: I used Blob in my database, but it didn't work for some reason I don't know. Can I contact you via email, please? I'd like to send you my work.